Converting a const char to wide char I get gibberish
This is an old legacy project under VS2008 with character set = Not Set in its settings.
I need to convert a non-wide character to a wide one using the following code.
const char*  test = "Καλημέρα";
size_t newsize = strlen(test) + 1;
wchar_t* wcstring = new wchar_t[newsize];
size_t convertedChars = 0;
mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, newsize, test, _TRUNCATE);

No matter what I can not convert the string test to wide. Where am I wrong here?


did you configure encoding (locale)? Since you are sing C-API you should invoke setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "<depends on your settings>"); when your program starts.

@MarekR No, this is not the case, but inside the resource I found this. LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)

Doc says: "mbstowcs_s uses the current locale for any locale-dependent behavior;"

Windows-1252 do not support Cyrillic script So this #pragma code_page(1252) is part of the problem.

it is not Cyrillic is Greek but anyway, I changed all the @pragma code_page to 1253 (greeks). No difference at all.

Take a look in this. Similar problem, but you are using C-API, so setlocale should be used. Note there are multiple pitfalls.

#pragma code_page will, at best, change how the compiler interprets the bits.  Not how the runtime interprets the bits.  Do you know exactly what bits your editor is putting in the source file when you type those greek characters?  If you don't, then don't type greek characters into your source file.  You have to know exactly what bits and under what encoding the data is under in order to convert it to 16 bit characters.

To make solving your problem sane, try to ensure your file is encoded in UTF-8, and ensure that your multibyte conversion is also from UTF-8 to UTF-16.  To test the conversion separate from the editing, use escape codes to put in "escaped UTF-8 values" into a character buffer, check that that gets converted, and then do it for typed characters.

Once you have UTF-8 to UTF-16 working - the simplest most sane situation - start thinking about other code pages.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont using the L literal before a raw string it works fine. ie string a = L"Καλημερα"

@Maverick I'm asking what the actual encoding in the actual file is, which that doesn't answer.  I gave you a set of steps to work out what is going wrong.  Basically you are converting from one encoding to another, unless the source, conversion and destination are all what you and your tools expect, you can't tell which of the 3 is wrong.  So lock down 2 out of 3 of the problems, solve the 3rd, and then repeat.

@Maverick You are making the assumption that because you greek string looks ok in whatever editor you are using that it will also be ok when you run your program. This is a unjustified assumption. Which is why you have to know 1) how your greek string is actually encoded and 2) what encoding your conversion method expects. If these two don't line up you're going to get gibberish.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont the actual file encoding is ansi

@Maverick ANSI is Windows speak for whatever code page your computer is set to use (which will definitely not be UTF-8).

The code page is windows-1253 for all files of the project

@Maverick I'm not used to using mbstowcs_s. Personally I would use MultiByteToWideChar which has the advantage that you can specify the code page to use explicitly instead of relying on the current locale.

@Maverick One other very important point, you say you are getting gibberish but you seem to be relying on the display in your debugger to prove that. I would not rely on that. It's probably right but the only way to be sure is to know what encodings to expect in your wide string. For example the Unicode for capital kappa is 0x039A so that it what you should except as the first value in your wide string. That's the only totally reliable way to know if it has worked or not.

@Maverick And similarly the CP-1253 encoding for capital kappa is 202, so that is what you should be looking for as the first byte in your narrow string to be sure that it is encoded in code page 1253. This is the only way to do this. Everything is just bytes, the encoding is how those bytes are interpreted and it's up to you to make sure that the encodings are correct. You get no help from Windows, C++ or your compiler in this.

@john I think you are right. Tracing the converted string to a new project seems to be right.
'EncodingTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'
'EncodingTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'





START >>>>>>Καλημέρα>>>>> END >>>>>>'EncodingTest.exe':






Is your problem solved? By the way, use setlocale to set code page 1253.

Thanks to all for their help. I changed the regional format settings to Windows System to Greek(Greece) to make it work for my C++ app.
Note: Despite the debugger output the TRACE command in the console outputs the conversion correctly.
